# Is minimizing the norm of a vector equivalent to minimizing the square of the norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, vector-analysis

Are the following two problems equivalent?

$$ \arg \min_{y} || A \vec{x} - \vec{y} || $$

and

$$ \arg \min_{y} || A \vec{x} - \vec{y} ||^2 $$

I feel like they are equivalent as it is just the square of a scalar ($|| A \vec{x} - \vec{y} || $) but I am never sure how things behave in higher dimensions (i.d. $\vec{y}$).

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent, as the norm of any vector is always a nonnegative real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Even though $\vec{y}$ may come from a multidimensional space, a norm is *always* a map from some space $X$ to the nonnegative real numbers, i.e. $\| \cdot \| \colon X \to \mathbb{R}_+$. Therefore they are equivalent.